# Unable to change keyboard shortcut for changing browser tabs in macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge, macos-monterey

In Edge, the keyboard shortcut to change tabs is `{control} tab`.

[image]

I set a custom application shortcut for Edge to use `{option} tab`:

[image]

[image]

But it still does not work. Pressing `{option} tab` does not change to the next tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing, unsuccessfully. Did you find a way to solve this problem in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   [& the reverse with  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> ] are actually Mac global commands, so it may not depend on the wording like it usually does. Safari & Finder, for instance, use the same key command but are worded differently.

[image]

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>    is global default for 'go to previous text or control area', which may mean you'd need to override that first.

You might be able to force this to work with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) but I don't have much experience with it. There are lists of pre-made 'recipes' you could look at.

In general, though, it's not really advisable to try to change global defaults.